# How to flush plots in IPython Notebook sequentially?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
for i in range(3):
   print("Info ",i)
   plt.figure()
   plt.plot(np.arange(10)*(i+1))
```

In an IPython Notebook, this will first print out the three info messages, and afterwards plot the three figures.

Which command can I use to enforce the sequential display of prints and plots? That is, print "Info 0", plot "Figure 0", print "Info 1", plot "Figure 1", etc.

This a simple bare-bones example. In my case it's much more complicated, and it's important to get the behavior correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply add `plt.show()` at the desired location.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

for i in range(3):
    print "Info ",i
    plt.plot(np.arange(10)*(i+1))
    plt.show()
```

Comment: This does not seem to work in VSCode Python Interactive

Comment: @Vedant: Bokeh worked quite well with VSCode Python Interactive. I found this brief example, included prints before and after the code and everything showed up as I expected: 

https://donjayamanne.github.io/pythonVSCodeDocs/docs/jupyter_examples/#Interactive-Plot-using-Bokeh

Answer (score 1):

`IPython` first evaluates all code in your cell. When this is done, open figures are plotted to the output area.

If that's not what you want, you can display your figures manually. However you have to be sure to close all newly created figure objects before the evaluation of the cell ends.

This is a short example:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import display

for i in range(3):
    print("Info ",i)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(np.arange(10)*(i+1))
    display(fig)
    plt.close()
```

Comment: This does not seem to work in VSCode Python Interactive

Comment: @Vedant: Bokeh worked quite well with VSCode Python Interactive. I found this brief example, included prints before and after the code and everything showed up as I expected: https://donjayamanne.github.io/pythonVSCodeDocs/docs/jupyter_examples/#Interactive-Plot-using-Bokeh